# Missing selection and navigation tools (icons) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gui, toolbar, navigation, qgis-1

I lost selection and navigation tools from the QGIS 1.8 toolbar when I tried drag then to different place.

I can't get them back anymore. Where they disappear? All these tools are checked but are still missing.

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

Toolbars are located outside your screen area.

You can use Python console to move them on screen.

Here is example of moving Navigation Toolbar:

```py
qgis.utils.iface.mapNavToolToolBar().move(10,10)
```

Names of other toolbars can be found by [this link](http://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html).

Comment: I had the same problem but with the advance digitizing one. Thanks to this I've got it back. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

A simple work-around is to change your screen to a lower resolution, drag the "missing" toolbar in position and switch back to the resolution of your choice. Works fine on Mac/Apple platforms.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall, clean registry with ccleaner.remove .qgis folder ( note the dot) reinstall.

Comment: No need to uninstall.  Just delete the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QuantumGIS\QGIS\UI`

Comment: Nathan - I can't seem to get this working. Do you just remove the .qgis folder and then delete the UI key and then restart QGIS?

Comment: Thanks Nathan, the Python console didn't work for me but your suggestion worked.