# In QGIS, layers properties dialog box is active but not visible. How do I get it back?

Tags: qgis

When I right click on a layer, then click on 'Properties'  I would expect the Properties dialog box to appear so I can change the style, add labels etc.  For some reason the box doesn't show.    It seems like the box is active but not visible - I say this because I can't click on anything else within QGIS until I press escape.  Many thanks for the help.

Comment: on windows, linux or mac?

Comment: @Mapperz - on Windows

Answer (score 3):

See [Missing tools (icons) QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/missing-tools-icons-qgis)

Alex Markov: *Toolbars are located outside your screen area. You can use Python console to move them on screen. Here is example of moving Navigation Toolbar:
qgis.utils.iface.mapNavToolToolBar().move(10,10)
Names of other toolbars can be found by this link.*

Nathan W: *delete the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QuantumGIS\QGIS\UI*

Comment: I'm quite new to this system. I did try to move the Layer Properties toolbox back onto the screen using the Python console and the following:
>qgis.utils.iface.showLayerProperties(QgsMapLayer*l).move(10,10) 

But, this error was returned:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'l' is not defined

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, so would appreciate more help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two screens (e.g. monitor + projector) the Properties menu might migrate to the second screen, and it will be invisible if that is not turned on. I just removed the HDMI cable from the back of my projector and the Properties window appeared in the first screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before. I didn't properly seek an answer at the time as I thought it was my computer or me having pressed something unwittingly. The way I found to resolve this was re-installation of qgis. Everything was 'back as it started'/ 'factory settings' as it were... So quite possible there is an option to check/uncheck somewhere. Good Luck!!

Comment: Uninstalling unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

To reset this (specific) dialog, open a python console and enter the following:

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().remove( "/Windows/VectorLayerProperties/geometry" )
```