# Missing layer tools in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-2, ux

I just installed QGis 2.0.1 and wanted to move the layer tools that were located on the very left hand side by default. I tried to move them to the top, next to all the other tools. Now, they just disappeared and I can't find them anywhere!

Where did they move to?

I checked all tools but still not there...

I'm very new to QGis, I already read something about Python but didn't get it and therefore didn't work. Also screen setting to lower resolution didn't work...

I would be really happy if someone could give me a very simple, step-by-step answer, where to click and what to do exactly!

Answer (score 1):

You need to right click anywhere in the Menu bar, and then a context Menu will open up. 
The toolbar you are looking for is called Manage Layers (atleast in the English Version. I'm not aware of what it is called in the German version)
You just need to select the 'Mange Layers' to get the Layers tool back.
[image]

Comment: I already ticked this, but then I get the overview of all my used layers. But what I want to have in the menu bar are the tools you find under "layer" e.g. "add WMS Layer", "add WFC layer", "add PostGIS layer" and so on (hope the translation is right, I'm using the German version)

Comment: @CaBu Please See my updated answer

Comment: still not workin :( it seems like when I dragged the tools and moved them, they somewhere dissapeared I can't see them but for QGis, they are still there (because I ticked "manage layers" but nothing happened visually) ... Usually, you can move the different tool groups in the menu bar by using your mouse and clicking on the grey dots left hand of the group. I did this, moved the group and then maybe left it somewhere "behind" the menu bar or so?? o.O The same happened to my colleauge and she coudn't figure it out either... :(

Comment: You could try renaming the qgis folder. A new folder will be made when you restart Qgis, and hopefully this should solve the issue. If you are on Windows it will be in `C:\Users\{username}\.qgis2` if you are on Linux it will be the `.qgis2/` folder in your home directory.

Comment: nope :( do you think I should try uninstalling and also renaming the folder? Only renaming does not work... I can't believe this seems to be so complicated!! seems as if I'm not the only one with this problem: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/missing-tools-icons-qgis but I really don't understand their solutions...

Comment: Have you tried the registry hack by NathanW: `Just delete the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QuantumGIS\QGIS\UI `

Comment: hmm... I would try it, but I don't know exactly what he means :( where do I enter this?

Comment: I finally got it by using the python konsole! what a long way... I still don't know where the layer menu was hiding all the time, but now I got it back :) Thanks a lot for trying to help me!!!